# Heapless linked list in no_std without malloc

Tags: linked-list, rust

What's missing from my attempt at a heapless linked list?

My goal is to get the below code to generate the sequence [1, 2, 3] on the stack and then print those values out on separate lines *without using `Box` or anything else requiring the heap or `std` or `malloc`*.

I've skimmed through https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists but all the "good" lists seem to depend on `Rc`, `Box`, etc.

The [`heapless` crate](https://japaric.github.io/heapless/heapless/index.html) is neat but requires knowing the size of a list beforehand.

My Google-fu isn't strong enough to find much help. Any pointers would be much appreciated. But here's what I'm thinking:

```rust
struct Node<'a, T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>
}

struct List<'a, T> {
    head: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>,
    tail: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>
}

impl<'a, T> List<'a, T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            head: None,
            tail: None
        }
    }

    fn push(self, value: T) ->Self {
        unimplemented!(); // What's missing here?
    }
}

struct Iter<'a, T> {
    next: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        match self.next.take() {
            Some(next) => {
                self.next = next.next;
                Some(&next.value)
            },
            None => None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for List<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Iter {
            next: self.head
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = List::new();
    let list = list.push(1);
    let list = list.push(2);
    let list = list.push(3);
    for item in list {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm stuck trying to implement `List.push`.

Comment: To clarify, you either need to place an upper limit on the size of the list and reserve that much stack space in advance, or use the heap. Those are your only options. If you can't see why, I recommend reading up on what the stack and heap are, and why they exist.

Comment: You could make the [push compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89b78d65f8c1fd7d9915c7fec2d6a61e), but lifetimes are not going to work very conveniently. Nodes are holding references in next rather than owning the next node. This allows you to avoid the sizing issue, but you can't allocate a node inside `push` with a lifetime long enough to be useful when you add the reference to the next node. To do this, you would need to create the Nodes somewhere they will live long enough — like in `main()` and pass references to `push()`. And that kind of sucks.

Comment: @JayDepp [I found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57010042/3063273) to let the compiler figure out what size it needs

Answer (score 1):

Allocating things on the stack without knowing their size (or at the very least an upper bound of their size) is squaring the circle and will not work. You can let the compiler figure out the size for you, but that is pretty much it. The reason for this is simple: Stack allocations may not fail and the compiler has to make sure everything fits in.

If you want to go ahead and stick with the `push(T)` signature, just taking a value Matt Thomas' answer is the way to go.

Here is my take on the issue, which avoids building nested types:

```rust
struct Node<'a, T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Node<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(value: T, next: Option<&'a Self>) -> Self {
        Node { value, next }
    }

    pub fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
        Iter {
            current: Some(self),
        }
    }
}

struct Iter<'a, T> {
    current: Option<&'a Node<'a, T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        match self.current {
            Some(Node { value, next }) => {
                self.current = *next;
                Some(value)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Allocation of the Nodes directly on the stack,
    // not inside a push method. <= Solves lifetime issues
    // Reversed order solves mutability issues.
    let three = Node::new(3, None);
    let two = Node::new(2, Some(&three));
    let one = Node::new(1, Some(&two));

    for item in one.iter() {
        println!("{}", item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a heapless stack that accomplishes the goals stated in the OP:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb26b12270bd0a523a693276ec36014f

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cons<T, U>(T, U);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyOption<T>(Option<T>);

trait Push<T>: Sized {
    fn push(self, value: T) -> Cons<Self, T>;
}

impl<T, U> Push<U> for Cons<T, U> {
    fn push(self, value: U) -> Cons<Self, U> {
        Cons(self, value)
    }
}

impl<T> Push<T> for T {
    fn push(self, value: T) -> Cons<Self, Self> {
        Cons(self, value)
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = U>, U> Cons<T, MyOption<U>> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<U> {
        match (self.1).0.take() {
            Some(u) => Some(u),
            None => self.0.next()
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for Cons<MyOption<T>, MyOption<T>> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.1).0.take() {
            Some(t) => Some(t),
            None => (self.0).0.take()
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Iterator<Item = U>, U> Iterator for Cons<Cons<T, MyOption<U>>, MyOption<U>> {
    type Item = U;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.1).0.take() {
            Some(u) => Some(u),
            None => self.0.next()
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for MyOption<T> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.0.take()
    }
}

fn create_stack() -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + core::fmt::Debug {
          MyOption(Some(0))
    .push(MyOption(Some(1)))
    .push(MyOption(Some(2)))
    .push(MyOption(Some(3)))
    .push(MyOption(Some(4)))
}

fn main() {
    let stack = create_stack();
    println!("Here's the stack:");
    println!("{:?}", stack);

    println!("Here are the items in reverse order");
    for item in stack {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Here's the stack:
Cons(Cons(Cons(Cons(MyOption(Some(0)), MyOption(Some(1))), MyOption(Some(2))), MyOption(Some(3))), MyOption(Some(4)))
Here are the items in reverse order
4
3
2
1
0
```

### Caveats

- You can't do `stack = stack.push(...)` in a loop (because `stack.push(...)` returns a different type)
- I didn't think at all about `Drop` behavior. I guess it would be recursive and blow up for large stacks
- This can create *huge* structs. Try not to move them around too much
- Is there a way to create an `Iterator` that doesn't require the `Cons` structs to hold `Option` types? And a way that can be iterated more than once? Maybe
- I suspect that every one of those impl functions is duplicated for every element in the resulting stack (since each element is of a different type and all the functions are generic)
- Every call to `.push()` can potentially copy `self` (not as in the `Copy` trait, but as in Rust could do a `memcpy` behind the scenes as part of the ownership move to keep things tidy on the stack)

Comment: This has the same drawback as using the heapless crate, as the compiler needs to know the size of the list beforehand to generate the types.

Comment: @MarkusKlein Yeah, the more I think about this the less I like it. It actually has _more_ disadvantages. And it's really not hard to write (in the case of the `heapless` crate) `Vec<i32, U7>` and then just change it to `Vec<i32, U8>` when you need to add an eighth element