# Can a struct of type E hold a reference to a different E without traits?

Tags: rust, struct

I would like to define a struct, `Env` which optionally contains a (mutable) reference to another `Env`, called it's `parent`. In all applications it can be easily shown that the `parent` will outlive the referencing `Env`. I cannot figure out how to express this in the type system however.

My first attempt led me to the following

```
struct Env<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut Env<'a>>
}
```

Which compiles, however the two `Env` objects now share the *same* lifetime parameter. The child `Env` has a shorter lifetime than the `parent` and so this quickly fails.

What I want to express, is something like the following:

```
struct Env<'r> {
    parent: Option<&'r mut Env<'e>> where 'e : 'r
}
```

The parent `Env` has some (different!) lifetime parameter `'b` which is longer than `'a` which ensures it will be safe. Trouble is if we make `'e` a parameter `Env` has two lifetime parameters and so we're back to where we started.

### Failing example

I'm working through Crafting Interpreters, it uses Environments to track the values stored in the interpreter. For the life of a rust function I would like to wrap the given environment in another environment. After the function exits the new environment is destroyed and the original environment is given back.

I've cut it back to the following (mostly minimal) example.

```
fn main() {
    let mut env = Env {
        parent: None,
        val: "Global".to_string(),
    };
    ex_block(3, &mut env);
}

struct Env<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut Env<'a>>,
    val: String,
}

impl<'a> Env<'a> {
    fn walk_up(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.val);
        match &mut self.parent {
            Some(env) => { env.walk_up(); },
            None => { }
        }
    }
}

fn ex_block<'r, 'e>(further_levels: u8, env: &'r mut Env<'e>) {
    if further_levels > 0 {
        let mut child: Env = Env {
            /* ERROR: This line somehow implies 'r must outlive 'e which is impossible */
            parent: Some(env), 
            val: format!("Level {}", further_levels),
        };
        ex_block(further_levels-1, &mut child);
    } else {
        env.walk_up();
    }
}
```

### Why don't you just make `Env` own its parent?

After one environment finishes it's lifetime the original environment needs to still exist. This is exactly what borrowing is for.

### Why don't you just put all the `Env` objects in an arena

Many online resources discussing trees suggest storing the nodes in a Vec and use indices instead of references. I've found unsatisfying as it just side steps the whole issue by re-implementing references as indices. It is less safe than using smart pointers in C++.

### Why don't you use some trait magic?

This is similar to [Generic struct with a reference to the same type but with any concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288640/generic-struct-with-a-reference-to-the-same-type-but-with-any-concrete-type) however, when I tried that I gained the following fun error:

> error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating   `ex_block::<Env<Env<Env<Env<Env<E...>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`

Making a trait and using `dyn` works but it requires a function lookup at runtime:

```
struct Env<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a mut dyn EnvTrait>,
}
```

Comment: Generics in Rust do not, by themselves, introduce any runtime overhead in the form of virtual function indirection. The *only* time Rust will use a virtual function table is if you have a trait object type using the `dyn` keyword. For generics that are *not* trait objects, Rust monomorphizes the function calls at compile-time, making them eligible for inlining. Are you open to a solution using generics that *doesn't* have any runtime overhead?

Comment: I am definitely open to a zero-overhead trait-based solution. I tried following the other question's style and got a recursive type which blew the compiler up (updated the question)

Comment: What you're doing is basically a linked list, so: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999204/heapless-linked-list-in-no-std-without-malloc

Comment: @Jmb I did take a look at that. All those lists own their items. The final "silly" one gets around my problem by creating nodes that only live inside the struct itself and give the result in a callback. The answers to the other question also both construct data structures that own the data, rather than just borrow it.

I would like to borrow the data as these environments form stacks on top of each other just before evaluation then may persist, or (in the easiest case) are deleted. The biggest example of this is the base Env, the global one.

Comment: I've done it using `dyn` and traits but it does mean paying an unnecessary penalty on every invocation (there's only one type that implements the trait).

Comment: [You can use shared references and `RefCell`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7681d2a7d08d33b3790925f1712762a5). This still introduces runtime penalty, though.

Comment: [Alternatively, use an arena, but one that gives references](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cde080d4209e7fcdea7864fbe49f96c6) ([`bumpalo`](https://docs.rs/bumpalo/latest/bumpalo/) isn't available on the playground, so this doesn't compile). This still includes a penalty of dynamic allocation (even if arena allocation is very fast), though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not that `Env` holds a reference to its parent. This is perfectly fine (as long as you don't create self-referential values, but that's another topic).

### Mutable references are invariant over T

The problem is caused by the fact that [the mutable reference of generic lifetimes are invariant](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-mut-t-is-not-covariant-with-t/54944) (see also [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27031)). In fact, if you rewrite your example using only non-mutable references, it works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let env = Env {
        parent: None,
        val: "Global".to_string(),
    };
    ex_block(3, &env);
}

struct Env<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a Env<'a>>,
    val: String,
}

impl Env<'_> {
    fn walk_up(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.val);
        if let Some(env) = self.parent {
            env.walk_up()
        }
    }
}

fn ex_block(further_levels: u8, env: &Env<'_>) {
    if further_levels > 0 {
        let child: Env = Env {
            parent: Some(env),
            val: format!("Level {}", further_levels),
        };
        ex_block(further_levels - 1, &child);
    } else {
        env.walk_up();
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=79aa89c970396b4b4c8d5c842641f241)

### Explanation for your example

As we've seen, mutable reference are invariant. This means that for some type `T` generic over a lifetime, `&mut T<'a>` cannot coerce into `&mut T<'b>` even if `'b` is narrower than `'a`. Since `Env<'a>` holds a `&mut Env<'a>`, it is also invariant. So `Env<'a>` cannot coerce into `Env<'b>`.

Now the first error in your code is caused by an attempt to coerce `&'r mut Env<'e>` into `&'e mut Env<'e>` (during assignment of `parent: Some(env)`), but there is no bound of `'r` over `'e` so the compiler raises the error.

If you change the `ex_block` function of your example slightly so that you only have one lifetime parameter:

```
fn ex_block<'e>(further_levels: u8, env: &'e mut Env<'e>) {
    if further_levels > 0 {
        let mut child: Env = Env {
            parent: Some(env), 
            val: format!("Level {}", further_levels),
        };
        ex_block(further_levels-1, &mut child);
    } else {
        env.walk_up();
    }
}
```

Then what happens is that the `&mut child` variable is a `&'child mut Env<'e>`, with `'child` being the lifetime of the local child variable that is only valid in the `if` branch scope. Again this variable cannot coerce into `&'child mut Env<'child>`, so the compiler tries to coerce `'child` into `'e` to turn the variable into `&'e mut Env<'e>`. That causes the error that the compiler finally outputs:

```
error[E0597]: `child` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:36
   |
24 | fn ex_block<'e>(further_levels: u8, env: &'e mut Env<'e>) {
   |             -- lifetime `'e` defined here
25 |     if further_levels > 0 {
26 |         let mut child: Env = Env {
   |             --------- binding `child` declared here
...
31 |         ex_block(further_levels-1, &mut child);
   |         ---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^-
   |         |                          |
   |         |                          borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `child` is borrowed for `'e`
32 |     } else {
   |     - `child` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Edit: Fixes my mistake where I stated that `&'a mut T` cannot coerce to `&'b mut T`, which is wrong.